# Understanding How Odometry Is Calculated In The Diff_Drive Controller

Tags: ros, diff-drive-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I apologize that this question has two parts.  If it's better to post two questions, then please let me know.

While reading through the source code of the [diff_drive_controller.cpp](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/blob/master/diff_drive_controller/src/diff_drive_controller.cpp), I am trying to understand how the two Odometry update methods work.

The "happy" path is the open loop update, which follows basic trigonometry, as defined by the Unicyle Kinematics.  Of course this is highly susceptible to dead reckoning because of drift, tire slip, bumps, etc.

The other update seems to be much more involved, calculates a mean position, and some extra steps before applying the trigonometry.

My first question is: Where can I find more information about the model behind the more involved update?

Secondly, even with the second method of update, this odometry calculation does not use any sensors at all, not even a wheel encoder.  Does this not create problems?  I understand if this is by design so that there's no dependency on any specific hardware; which is a goal of this project.

But then how can I incorporate my own sensors into the control loop?  How can I also add some PID to the loop as well?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381147/understanding-how-odometry-is-calculated-in-the-diff_drive-controller/) by [sameh4](https://answers.ros.org/users/76665/sameh4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2021-06-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you are talking about [Odometry::updateOpenLoop()](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/blob/bdd9e260742941ca3e887f46391dc62f51b4ec4d/diff_drive_controller/src/odometry.cpp#L88) vs. [Odometry::update()](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/blob/bdd9e260742941ca3e887f46391dc62f51b4ec4d/diff_drive_controller/src/odometry.cpp#L48) (used in diff_drive_controller.cpp [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/blob/54dd7837dc0cff1445eb06f36a152d3d3bd41bb1/diff_drive_controller/src/diff_drive_controller.cpp#L187) and [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/blob/54dd7837dc0cff1445eb06f36a152d3d3bd41bb1/diff_drive_controller/src/diff_drive_controller.cpp#L209) respectively)?

If so, I don't know of any formal documentation, but I find the code reasonably clear if you follow it through. There isn't much change between the math performed in each. The big difference is the information used to perform the odometric estimate.

The Open Loop update uses the *commanded* linear and angular velocities and the time step to estimate where the robot moved to (assuming perfect response of the vehicle to the control input).

The "closed loop" update uses *measured* wheel positions to get an improved estimate of the distance the robot actually travelled. If there is more than one wheel per side (e.g. for skid steer robots), then the average position of the wheels on each side is taken to hopefully reduce noise / uncertainty / the effect of slip.

Regardless of whether open or closed loop is used, both methods use the same RungaKutta2 implementation to update the odometric estimate.

Both methods are susceptible to drift over time due to slip and other sources of uncertainty, though certainly using position feedback will result in lower drift than the fully open-loop approach.

If you want to mitigate unbounded drift over time, then you need to incorporate other local/global measurement sources. One of the most popular ways to do this in ROS/ROS2 is with the [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) package, which will incorporate IMU and GPS data and other odometry sources (e.g. visual odometry) to improve your robots pose estimate.

As far as modifying the control loop to add additional feedback goes, it really depends on your application. diff_drive_controller is open-loop with respect to whatever hardware interface it is interacting with. It sets the velocity that would be appropriate for the desired body twist. If under the hood you want to modify the *velocity* controller to behave a certain way or incorporate certain feedback, you can certainly do so. In most applications, however, your goal is to meet a target *position* (the intermediate velocities are often less important). If so, then I'd recommend using the [navigation2](https://navigation.ros.org/) package. As long as you're publishing odometry and, localizing the robot if applicable, nav2 will perform the closed loop position control for you.

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sameh4](https://answers.ros.org/users/76665/sameh4/) on 2021-06-27**:
Thanks Simon!  This was a very helpful answer.  I previously studied this book on SLAM extensively https://github.com/gaoxiang12/slambook-en, so I have a good background.  I have also wanted to checkout the nav2 package but I am taking baby steps with ROS2

**Comment by [Neuromorphic](https://answers.ros.org/users/13466/neuromorphic/) on 2021-08-17**:
@shonigmann

> In most applications, however, your goal is to meet a target position (the intermediate velocities are often less important). If so, then I'd recommend using the navigation2 package. As long as you're publishing odometry and, localizing the robot if applicable, nav2 will perform the closed loop position control for you.

I would be grateful if you could point out why nav2 might be preferable over nav1 (Ros 1  move_base) in this case?

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-08-17**:
The question was tagged with ros2 and foxy, so the answer focused on ros2/nav2 and wasn't meant to compare with nav1.

Its been a while since I've looked at nav1, but it should achieve largely the same functionality. Nav2 is a bit more modern and has received more recent attention. Nav1 may have more legacy functionality, but I think Nav2 is quickly catching up. You can find some additional details on the differences here: https://navigation.ros.org/about/ros1_comparison.html#ros1-comparison